# Sending a message without callback. PHP / Workerman

Tags: php, tcp

Is it possible to send a message to the user without calling the onMessage callback using the parameter $data for encode? I tried to insert the $ data parameter into the onConnect callback, but it gives me an error. $tcp_worker->onConnect = function($connection, $data).

````
use Workerman\Worker;
use Workerman\Lib\Timer;
 
// #### Creating ####
$tcp_worker = new Worker("tcp://0.0.0.0:8000");
 
// process count
$tcp_worker->count = 20;
 
// onConnect callback
$tcp_worker->onConnect = function($connection)
{
    echo "New connection from ip " . $connection->getRemoteIp() . " " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ."\n";  
};
 
// recieve on data from user
$tcp_worker->onMessage = function($connection, $data)
{
    // sending data to user
    $connection->send(" \$KE,WR,1,1 $data \n");
    echo " \$KE $data \n";
};
 
$tcp_worker->onMessage = function($connection, $data)
{
    // $ data is the result Websocket :: decode ($ recv_buffer)
    var_dump($data);
    $connection->send('receive success');
};
 
// close connection
$tcp_worker->onClose = function($connection)
{
    echo "Connection closed\n";
    $Workerconnection = false;
};
 
 
 
Worker::runAll(); ```
````